# Drupal 7 module - page layout changes

Tags: 7, hooks

I'm new to Drupal development and this question may have been asked and answered but I haven't found an answer that works for me yet.

I am developing a module that creates 4 paths using a menu_hook. Three of the pages appear inside an iframe defined on a page. I'd like to prevent the header/sidebars/footer (and other regions other than content) from appearing on the iframed page. This must be done independent of the theme - I don't know or care what the theme is.

I'd like the iframed page to only contain the  content  tags. I want to do this programmatically without the help of any additional modules. The iframed page executes a js script (on load) that redirects (the parent) to a results page. It is during the redirect that I can see the loaded iframed page and then the redirection occurs. The transition is ugly.

I have tried using templates in the module directory; however, I don't think I've done them correctly and haven't yet encountered a good example of a template loaded and used from a module directory.

I have tried a hook_page_alter function to **unset** the regions (but the header and footer still appear on the page).

I've tried a theme_hook function but I'm only interested in suppressing some of the regions the theme may be using and not interested in variables.

Because I don't know what the theme is and I don't know what the selector names or classes might be for the page divs I don't want to try and solve this with a few "display:none;" entries in a css file. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Module:**

- [The Empty Page module](https://drupal.org/project/empty_page) is a simple empty page solution. It provides an interface that assists in managing "empty" menu callbacks, mostly used for pages that only consist of blocks.
- [The Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module allows a site administrator to create customized layouts for multiple uses.
- [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) allows you to manage contextual conditions and reactions for different portions of your site. For each context, you can choose what blocks to show.

**Theming:**

- [Template suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/223440) are alternate templates based on existing .tpl.php files. You can write in [preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7) , where put condition and if true, assign page template to page--empty.tpl.php - here you should remove all regions printing except content - so you will get empty page.